# Stacking Controls vertically in a grid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I got the following Paper element with some checkboxes in:

[image]

I want them to be stacked vertically though, and I can't quite figure out how. My Paper element is in a Grid Item:

```
<Grid item xs={1} spacing={4}>
    <Paper className={classes.paper}>
        <Typography>(currently empty)</Typography>
        {this.getBoxesWithLabels(this.getLevelLabels(4, -3))}
    </Paper>
</Grid>
```

and thus it won't have much space on the UI (which is intended). How would I go about this? I've tried to use justifyContent, justifySelf, alignItems and others, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: What are your `classes.paper` styles?

Comment: @markmoxx That's from Google's own material classes

Comment: Try putting a grid *inside* your paper component

Comment: @markmoxx Huh. Yeah putting in a grid in the paper element, making it a container rather than item and then set the direction to "column" it works pretty nicely

Comment: Ha yeah, I just answered with the same :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Grid item xs={1} spacing={4}>
    <Paper className={classes.paper}>
        <Grid direction="column">
            <Typography>(currently empty)</Typography>
            {this.getBoxesWithLabels(this.getLevelLabels(4, -3))}
        </Grid>
    </Paper>
</Grid>
```